# In Mongodb, how to update many sub-documents inside a document?

Tags: mongodb

My UserContactModal has arrayPropery of RateCards whish is a subSchema inside UserContactsSchema.

I am trying to update all those rateCards whose _id not equal to requested rateCardId but the match count shows 0. here is my query;

```
await userContactsModel.updateMany(
          {
            _id: contactId,
            user,
            "rateCards._id": { $ne: ObjectId(rateCardId) },
          },
          {
            $set: {
              "rateCards.$.makeDefault": false,
            },
          }
        );
```

Comment: if `match count shows 0`, then the filter in first document is incorrect. You should investigate it, for example make it find the document you expect to see updated via simple find and then repeat update again